# Getting Google Cloud Text to Speech to work using cURL or Python

Tags: python, curl, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-text-to-speech

I tried following the following advice:

[Google Cloud Text To Speech API Quickstart example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705976/google-cloud-text-to-speech-api-quickstart-example)

[Google Cloud Text-to-Speech Interface Confusion (How do I download the mp3 files?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766683/google-cloud-text-to-speech-interface-confusion-how-do-i-download-the-mp3-files)

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

but I just can't get it to work, even with all this information.
Regarding the step-by-step-guides, I'm stuck at:

"And then you can use the curl command like so" or "3) They provided a sample request to general a file:"

Where does the code get entered? Powershell only gives me errors, which are in German unfortunately, so I tried translating them. I don't think it's intended to use the code there, since I'm doing nothing else than copy and paste the lines with my credentials.

Here's the error in question, when I paste the code of link #2, step 3) in the Powershell:

```
In line: 3 characters: 5
+ --data "{
+ ~
Expression is missing after the unary operator "-".
In line: 3 characters: 5
+ --data "{
+ ~~~~
Unexpected token "data" in expression or statement.
In line: 3 characters: 9
+ --data "{
+ ~
In the section "Data" the associated statement block is missing.
In line: 17 characters: 6
+} "" https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize "> synth ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~
Unexpected Token "" https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize "" in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Comment: I could reproduce the same error in a Windows environment and I think the issue here is how you specifies the cUrl. As I can see, the command should be different in PS as explained [some other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl). However, I'm not familiar with PS and you may do further research about that.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with [Google Cloud Text-to-Speech Interface Confusion (How do I download the mp3 files?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766683/google-cloud-text-to-speech-interface-confusion-how-do-i-download-the-mp3-files). I got this error in the step `3)` and I guess it is what you see:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

So my issue here is the authentication. To solve this, I have followed the steps in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started):

1. Download Service Account key as JSON file
2. Run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"` (I'm using a Linux environment)

In your case, you should have run `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"` since you are using Powershell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I should have clarified better - I'm sorry. The authentication process seemed to be successful, at least it is not the culprit of my problem right now. I translated the error code and edited my post. I'm not well experienced regarding programming, but it looks like I'm using a syntax the powershell cannot work with. Since it wasn't clarified any further what to do with the code in step 3), I honestly just pasted it into the terminal, but that didn't go too well... Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?